# thunderbird: set default dictionary

Tags: thunderbird, language

In addition to the default english dictionary (myspell-en-us), I have installed german dictionary.

Now it seems german is set to default. Every time I compose a message, german is selected as default.

Changing "Preferences -> Composition -> Language" to english does not have any effect, german is still selected as default in a new message.

Can somebody please advise how to set englidh dictionary as default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem for some time.
For me what worked was installing again the diccionary that I want as default and then selecting them in the Options:

Menu -> Tools -> Options -> Composition -> Spelling -> Language

It is also from this very same place whence you can download and install the dictionary you need.

Comment: This is broken in Thunderbird 115.8 (the newest at the time of writing). Broken in the sense that after deselecting all spell checking options and dictionaries and restarting TB, the first language in the dictionary list is still checked and all new messages default to that.

Answer (score 7):

Setting the default language for spelling checking in the new message editor in Thunderbird:

Menu - Settings - Composition - Spelling - Language

Comment: Under ubuntu 18.04 TB 60.5.1 the options is under Menu > Edit > Preferences > Composition: [spelling sub-tab] The tabs on my system don't look like tabs so I over looked it as just a line of text, but they are indeed tabs.